# Why can't I pass an argument to fragment using navigation component when that argument has a default value?

Tags: android, navigation, arguments

I am using navigation component and I don't understand why I get an error passing the argument to the method below if the argument is defined. I am using SafeArgs and I only get this error when I define a default value for this argument.

[image]

Could someone explain me why this happens and how can I solve it?

Here is a part of the code of the navigation graph.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/sleepTrackerFragment"
        android:name="com.example.sleeptracker.fragments.sleep_tracker.SleepTrackerFragment"
        android:label="fragment_sleep_tracker"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sleep_tracker" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sleepTrackerFragment_to_sleepQualityFragment"
            app:destination="@id/sleepQualityFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="qualityLastSleep"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="-1" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/sleepQualityFragment"
        android:name="com.example.sleeptracker.fragments.sleep_quality.SleepQualityFragment"
        android:label="fragment_sleep_quality"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sleep_quality" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sleepQualityFragment_to_sleepTrackerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/sleepTrackerFragment" >
        </action>
    </fragment>
```

Comment: Hi there, did you try clean and rebuild? Sometimes it worked for me if I had just added some argument

Comment: @ravi Yeah, I did it and I had the same problem

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in documentation

> Destination-level arguments and default values are used by all actions that navigate to the destination. If needed, you can override the default value of an argument (or set one if it doesn't already exist) by defining an argument at the action level. This argument must be of the same name and type as the argument declared in the destination.

so you have to override this value to do so you can follow any of the both solutions below

**solution one**

```
 val action =  SleepQualityFragmentDirections.actionSleepQualityFragmentToSleepTrackerFragment()
 action.qualityLastSleep = 5 // your value
 findNavController().navigate(action)
```

---

**solution two**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/sleepTrackerFragment"
    android:name="com.example.sleeptracker.fragments.sleep_tracker.SleepTrackerFragment"
    android:label="fragment_sleep_tracker"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sleep_tracker" >
   <argument
           android:name="qualityLastSleep"
           app:argType="integer"
           android:defaultValue="-1" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_sleepTrackerFragment_to_sleepQualityFragment"
        app:destination="@id/sleepQualityFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/sleepQualityFragment"
    android:name="com.example.sleeptracker.fragments.sleep_quality.SleepQualityFragment"
    android:label="fragment_sleep_quality"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sleep_quality" >
    
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_sleepQualityFragment_to_sleepTrackerFragment"
        app:destination="@id/sleepTrackerFragment" >
     <argument
           android:name="qualityLastSleep"
           app:argType="integer"
           android:defaultValue="-1" />
       
    </action>
</fragment>
```

and then you can call your navigation like this

```
findNavController().navigate(SleepQualityFragmentDirections.actionSleepQualityFragmentToSleepTrackerFragment(5))
```

Comment: It's so ugly and akward to do this tbh, typical Android.

Comment: Solution 1 worked perfectly for me. Thanks man! You just saved me from more hours of misery

Comment: Uhm, that's a weird design, was stuck on this for a while but this helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

seems like what you really want is destination level argument:

Try the following:

```xml
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/sleepTrackerFragment"
        android:name="com.example.sleeptracker.fragments.sleep_tracker.SleepTrackerFragment"
        android:label="fragment_sleep_tracker"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sleep_tracker" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sleepTrackerFragment_to_sleepQualityFragment"
            app:destination="@id/sleepQualityFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/sleepQualityFragment"
        android:name="com.example.sleeptracker.fragments.sleep_quality.SleepQualityFragment"
        android:label="fragment_sleep_quality"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sleep_quality" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sleepQualityFragment_to_sleepTrackerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/sleepTrackerFragment" >
            <argument
               android:name="qualityLastSleep"
               app:argType="integer"
               android:defaultValue="-1" />
        </action>
    </fragment>
```

You can also Ctrl+Click on `actionSleepQualityFragmentToSleepTrackerFragment()` to check if the generated function accepts an argument.

Do try clean and rebuild if IDE complains about argument passing

Doc link: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#override_a_destination_argument_in_an_action

Let me know if this does not work for you

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work. In fact, in the design section of the navigation graph it doesn't recognise any argument if I only put the argument inside the action

Comment: Hi there @MartiSerraMolina Did you also check the generated function by Ctrl+Click on `actionSleepQualityFragmentToSleepTrackerFragment()` ? I reckon this does not have any argument?